# How to get rid of the space above the text in table's cell after setting boldness manually?

Tags: tables

How to get rid of the space above the text in table's cell after setting boldness manually? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}       
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{xfakebold}

\newcommand{\fbseries}{\unskip\setBold\aftergroup\unsetBold\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBoldness}[1]{\def\fake@bold{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setBoldness{2}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Name} &
\multirow{2}{*}{H} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
\multirow{2}{*}{Note} \\
\cline{3-8}
 & & {\fbseries BAD} & J & K & L & M & N & \\
\hline
A &   4180 &    &  &  &  & & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you need all the aftergroup tricks just to set bold? surely this is a local settinmg and will revert at the end of the group anyway?

Comment: I need something not so bold, something in between. I found this method.

Answer (score 1):

> I need something not so bold, something in between...

Assuming you're using the Computer Modern font family, I suggest you employ its **non-extended bold** font weight. Happily, this font weight exhibits none of the idiosyncracies [!] of the "fake bold" (fb) font weight you've cobbled together. And, it's quite a bit narrower than Computer Modern's standard bold, aka **extended bold**, font weight.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{xfakebold}
%% Do you need \unskip, \aftergroup [twice!], and \ignorespaces?
\newcommand{\fbseries}{\setBold}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBoldness}[1]{\def\fake@bold{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\nbold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\setBoldness{2}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l| *{6}{X|} l|}
\hline
Name & 4180 & \fbseries BAD & J & K & L & M & N & Note\\ \hline
B    & 4180 & \nbold BAD    & O & P & Q & R & S &     \\ \hline
C    & 4180 & \bfseries BAD & T & U & V & W & X &     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```